# How can I tell if an Outlook.MailItem / Outlook.Conversation is ignored or not?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

From a mail item I can get the conversation

```
var conv = mailItem.GetConversation();
if( conv != null )
{
   //
}
```

But the user can select to 'ignore' the conversation.

How can I tell if a certain conversation has been ignored?

Answer (score 0):

The [ConversationID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867895(v=office.15).aspx) property associates items with a conversation. These items and the conversation all have the same value in their ConversationID property. So, if there is no item with the same conversation ID the user chose to ignore the existing conversation or there are no other items from the conversation. Try to play with any low-level property explorer such as MFCMAPI and see what properties are changed when a user chooses to ignore the conversation. Also you may consider handling the `PropertyChange` event of Outlook items to track property changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ignored conversations are stored in a hidden folder named "Conversation Action Settings". It is on the same level as the Inbox, but hidden:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder csFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders["Conversation Action Settings"];
```

The items are stored in the associated contents table. You can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMsgStore button, Open Root Container, go to the GetHierarchyTable tab, double click on the IPM_SUBTREE folder, go to the GetHierarchyTable tab again, double click on the "Conversation Action Settings" folder, go to the "Associated Contents" tab.

The only way to access associated messages in the Outlook Object Model is through `MAPIFolder.GetStorage`. It will not let you access all hidden items or search for a particular item - you can only go by the message class (which will be "IPM.ConversationAction" for all conversation items), subject, or the entry id. You can of course go by the subject, but it is not unique - you can have multiple conversations with the same subject, but one of them ignored, and another one is not.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) is an option, it treats associated messages as as regular items (accessible through [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).HiddenItems), so you can search (`RDOFolder.HiddenItems.Find / FindNext / Restrict` or `RDOFolder.HiddenItems.MAPITable.ExecSQL`). It also allows to search on binary properties (such as `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX`, which is what Outlook uses to find the conversation).